# ADODB in ASP.NET Reference Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, com, adodb

I have an ASP.NET based web application. I created all the folders by hand, so the full structure is as below.

```
    ROOT
        sendmail.aspx
        Web.config
    App_Code
        sendmail.cs
    bin
        Interop.ADODB.dll
        Interop.CDO.dll
```

My web.config is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation>
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="ADODB, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This setup has worked in the past. However, we've recently updated our test computers to Windows 7. The server is Windows Server 2005. I know there were deprecation issues between 7 sp1 and older version in regards to ADODB. I've installed the hotfix for that, and recompiled the dlls, then moved them to the server. However, now I am getting the below error on compile. I'm uncertain as to why it is not correctly referencing the dll.

```
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0012: The type 'ADODB.Fields' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ADODB, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
```

.

Answer (score 0):

put that in your web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="ADODB, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

should fix your error

Comment: I don't have a web.config. How do I go about creating one? I've never needed them in the past.

Comment: just add it to your project like described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815179/en

Comment: I've added the Web.Config file, but there is no change to the issue.

Comment: have you also added a reference (to ADODB) in the project? over Solution-Explorer -> right-click on your project -> add reference

Comment: There is no project. I created the files listed above in the folders above using a text based editor. I did not create a project in an IDE.

Comment: ok, never heard from someone that this works. so i think i cant help you out